# Relation adding not working in Drupal 7.9

Tags: 7

I am a adding a new relationaship type, when i add up its not adding up, it gives one more time asking for details for input of relationship type and when i give the details and add it an fatal error displays..

I am using Drupal 7.9 and latest versions of modules on Drupal.org
below is the error message

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctools_export_crud_load_multiple() in R:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\sites\all\modules\relation\relation.module on line 397
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a known incompatibility with CTools rc1; use the development snapshot, and it will work.

Comment: It's true. There's even an explicit block on ctools-rc1 in the info file "dependencies[] = ctools (!=7.x-1.0-rc1)", so either you have a too old -dev, or a pre rc version.